# How to delete firebase Authentication Users from Android App?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[Firebase dashboard view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr75i.png)

I need to remove A user from firebase authenticated Users list - using my mobile application. Authentication method is email and password authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow application to delete user in the console, there is no pure `client-side` solution. As far as i've known, there are two option.

1. User `Firebase cloud function` to delete user when specific event occur to Firebase database.
2. Create backend with `Admin SDK` and build endpoints for user to call an manipulate user data.

Comment: not the current user. i want to give admin access to a user so admin can remove other users as well.

Comment: So there is no other way to do it using android. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> The Firebase Admin SDK allows deleting existing users by their uid:
>   for reference: [Check this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().deleteUserAsync(uid).get();
System.out.println("Successfully deleted user.");
```

**For app you can create API that will call this block on server. e.g. deleteUserCall() that takes email or userId as parameter and on server side against that userId you can delete that user**

Comment: Can Android app install Admin SDK ? Maybe this code should be implemented on server side.

Comment: Yes , For android he needs to create API to call that will call above code from backend!

Comment: is there a way to do it without creating an API call. because I'm developing this using firebase backend only.

Answer (score 3):

To remove an other user you have to use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

[Here an example to delete a user with the id.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user)

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
.then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully deleted user");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
});
```

**(You must be logged as an admin)**

Then you can create an [HTTP Trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) to call this function with parameters.

Comment: Hi there, can you please explain more on this, I am trying to delete all user accounts, but this cloud functions really confuses me. I am building a mobile with react native, I have cloud functions enabled. I looked through the docs , and I found that I can get all users ` `https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users` and then I can put the function you wrote inside it, but not sure how to trigger this !

Comment: @Yasir Umh I don't know how to be more clear, add an HTTP Trigger in your Firebase Cloud Functions, loop on all users and delete one by one.