# How to delete other user using Firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

As I understand, it is not possible for one user to delete another user in the firebase. From previous [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409048/how-to-delete-firebase-authentication-users-from-android-app) I learn that I can use firebase functions for that. Each user has a document in the cloud firebase (path: `/users/userPhoneNumber/{age,height,...}`). Once the document is deleted, I want to delete the user from the firebase authentication. I know how to catch a change in the cloud firebase using function (although I'm not sure how to catch a deletion), but the problem I'm having is how can I delete the user? I'm using Java for my app side and javascript for my funcations side. As I understand, the user should have the app installed on the phone in order to delete his authentication.

Comment: So, on deletion of the user document in the Firestore `users` collection, you want to delete the user in the Auth service. Is that right? What is the id of the document in the `users` collection? the user phone number?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes you understood correctly. As I understand it's the only way to delete the user from the Auth service (if not, please tell me how). The document id is user's phone number.

Comment: The clients SDKs offer a method for deleting the user (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#delete) for the JS SDK) but **only the signed in user can delete his own account**, not another user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the user's Firestore document ID is the user's phone number, you can write a Cloud Function as follows, by using the Admin SDK [`getUserByPhoneNumber()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getuserbyphonenumber) and [`deleteUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#deleteuser) methods.

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userPhoneNbr}')
    .onDelete(async (snap, context) => {
        
        try {
            
            const userPhoneNbr = context.params.userPhoneNbr;
            const userRecord = await admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(userPhoneNbr);
            await admin.auth().deleteUser(userRecord.uid);
            return null;
            
        } catch (error) {
            
            // ....
            
        }

    });
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! Any idea how to log out all sessions that the user is logged in before removing it?